# How to set DrawerList side and other side background color

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: Please look the image first.]

I want to change right side gray bgcolor to other or transparent when drawer menu opened.

This is **Main Layout**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/xxxx"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/custom_toolbar" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/nav_drawer_linear_layout" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is **nav_drawer_linear_layout**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvDrawerList"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i cannot not edit page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to use following line that obscures primary content while a drawer is open

`mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.WHITE or <whichever color you intend to use>)`

Hope that helps!

Comment: it is ok.thank for ur help.:)

Answer (score 0):

in your xml in parent layout put this `android:background="#ffeeeeee"`

Comment: It is not ok, i already use this in  "nav_drawer_linear_layout".

Comment: change android:background="@android:color/white" with android:background="#ffeeeeee"

Comment: It is only change left side.

Comment: if you want to change all put it inside android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

Comment: thank for ur help. I think that right side bgcolor is depend on active activity bgcolor or fragment bgcolor.